# boost.python: Argument types did not match C++ signature

Tags: c++, python, boost, c++11, boost-python

I am having a strange problem when calling a C++ function in python.

I exposed a class from which I want to call a function:

```
class_<MyClass, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>("MyClass", init<>())
    // ...
    .def("someFunc", &MyClass::someFunc)
;
```

I get a `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` from a member variable from another class which is exposed via `.def_readonly(...)`

When I try to call the function, I get the following error:

```
File "pytest.py", line 27, in test_func
    cu.someFunc("string")
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.someFunc(MyClass, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    result(MyClass{lvalue}, std::string)
```

As far as I see, the signatures **do** match.
Does someone see the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tracked in this [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6545), Boost.Python does not fully support `std::shared_ptr`.

In short, two easy solutions are to either:

- Use `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`.
- Expose the `std::shared_ptr` member variable with via `add_property()`, providing a [`boost::python::return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html#return_value_policy-spec) with a type of [`boost::python::return_by_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_by_value.html#return_by_value-spec).

---

While the signatures in the exception look the same, the subtle detail is that the Python `MyClass` object embeds a `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`.  Thus, Boost.Python must perform a conversion from an `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` to an lvalue `MyClass`.  However, Boost.Python does not currently support [custom lvalue conversions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#question2).  Thus, an `ArgumentError` exception is thrown.

When exposing member variables with `def_readonly("spam", &Factory::spam)`, it is the equivalent of exposing it via:

```cpp
add_property("spam", make_getter(&Factory::spam, return_internal_reference()))
```

Boost.Python has special code when the type being exposed in this manner is a `boost::shared_ptr`.  As it is a read-only property and `std::shared_ptr` is intended to be copied, it is safe to expose a copy of `std::shared_ptr` with a return value policy with a type of `return_by_value`.

Here is a complete example where `Factory` exposes a `Spam` object held by `std::shared_ptr` and an `Egg` object held by `boost::shared_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // std::shared_ptr, std::make_shared
#include <string>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup Spam type.
struct Spam
{
  ~Spam() { std::cout << "~Spam()" << std::endl; }

  void someFunc(std::string str)
  {
    std::cout << "Spam::someFunc() " << this << " : " << str << std::endl;
  }
};

/// @brief Mockup Egg type.
struct Egg
{
  ~Egg() { std::cout << "~Egg()" << std::endl; }

  void someFunc(std::string str)
  {
    std::cout << "Egg::someFunc() " << this << " : " << str << std::endl;
  }
};

/// @brief Mockup Factory type.
struct Factory
{
  Factory()
    : spam(std::make_shared<Spam>()),
      egg(boost::make_shared<Egg>())
  {
    spam->someFunc("factory");
    egg->someFunc("factory");
  }

  std::shared_ptr<Spam>   spam;
  boost::shared_ptr<Egg>  egg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose Factory class and its member variables.
  python::class_<Factory>("Factory")
    // std::shared_ptr<Spam>
    .add_property("spam", python::make_getter(&Factory::spam,
        python::return_value_policy<python::return_by_value>()))
    // boost::shared_ptr<Egg>
    .def_readonly("egg", &Factory::egg)
    ;

  // Expose Spam as being held by std::shared_ptr.
  python::class_<Spam, std::shared_ptr<Spam>>("Spam")
    .def("someFunc", &Spam::someFunc)
    ;

  // Expose Egg as being held by boost::shared_ptr.
  python::class_<Egg, boost::shared_ptr<Egg>>("Egg")
    .def("someFunc", &Egg::someFunc)
    ;
}
```

Interactive Python demonstrating usage and object lifetime:

```python
>>> import example
>>> factory = example.Factory()
Spam::someFunc() 0x8d73250 : factory
Egg::someFunc() 0x8d5dbc9 : factory
>>> factory.spam.someFunc("python")
Spam::someFunc() 0x8d73250 : python
>>> factory.egg.someFunc("python")
Egg::someFunc() 0x8d5dbc9 : python
>>> factory = None
~Egg()
~Spam()
>>> factory = example.Factory()
Spam::someFunc() 0x8d73250 : factory
Egg::someFunc() 0x8d06569 : factory
>>> spam = factory.spam
>>> factory = None
~Egg()
>>> spam.someFunc("python")
Spam::someFunc() 0x8d73250 : python
>>> spam = None
~Spam()
>>> factory = example.Factory()
Spam::someFunc() 0x8d73250 : factory
Egg::someFunc() 0x8ce10f9 : factory
>>> egg = factory.egg
>>> factory = None
~Spam()
>>> egg.someFunc("python")
Egg::someFunc() 0x8ce10f9 : python
>>> egg = None
~Egg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but this may work:

```
boost::python::register_ptr_to_python<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>();
```

Source:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/register_ptr_to_python.html