# boost.python argumentError with py to c

Tags: python, c++, boost

I use openssl aes encrypt source code to make a file "my-aes.cpp" and in the last of "my-aes.cpp", I write that:

And then, make successfully,I write "test.py" to test openssl aes encrypt:
[image]

However,when I input "python test.py":
[image]

As far as I see, the signatures do match. Does someone see the problem?

Comment: Please paste actual code, not a screenshot of code.

Comment: Seems very similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825662/boost-python-argument-types-did-not-match-c-signature#20843509](python argument types did not match).   It's difficult to review your C++ parts that are not shown.